# How to identify whole English words mixed in Chinese characters?

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm using word boundaries to match whole English words. It works fine if the string I'm matching against is in pure English.

ex: `SELECT 'a word a' REGEXP '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]' -> 1`

but if the string contains any Chinese literals,

ex: `SELECT 'a word哈哈抓不到我吧 a' REGEXP '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]' -> 0`

How can I make my queries more intelligent so as to catch the English word hiding with the Chinese words?

I'm thinking `REGEXP '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]] | [Chinese]word[[:>:]] | [[:<:]]word[Chinese] | [Chinese]word[Chinese]'` but I don't know how to use Unicode points in mysql regexp...

Answer (score 0):

You can regex unicode characters in most languages using an escaped 'u' plus the unicode hex (ex. `\u0041` is 'A').  You could then match a unicode range.  This is all capital basic latin letters ie A-Z:

```
[\u0041-\u005A]
```

[Good resource](http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block)

Always double check your encodings, too.

An example to match `'a word哈哈抓不到我吧 a'` including spaces:

```
.*[\u0041-\u0054 \u0061-\u007a \u0020].*
```

In ascii, this would be:

```
.*[A-Za-z ].*
```

Comment: It is indeed correct for most languages, but I don't think mySQL REGEXP supports this.

Comment: I need it to match whole words, so I changed it to `'.*word.*'`, it would then become greedy due to the `.*` in front and behind.

Comment: I went around and used `[^a-zA-Z]word[^a-zA-Z]` instead, it works fine for now, but I don't know if it is strict enough.

Comment: I suppose it would fail if there were an accented literal in front or behind, but luckily I don't have any accented literals. But I still hope there is a way to pinpoint the exact Unicode range you want to match.

Comment: If [^a-zA-Z] works then just stick to that.  The .* would be greedy, that's my bad.